# Get PrimarySMTP using GetExchangeUser

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

In Excel version 2201, using VBA, I would like to get the PrimarySMTP property for a list of mail users for which I have the display name.

I have written code that works in most cases:

```vb
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 

Set myNameSpace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 

Set MyAddrList = myNameSpace.addressLists("Global Address List") 

Set myAddrEntries = MyAddrList.AddressEntries(strDisplayname) 

Set objExchUsr = myAddrEntries.GetExchangeUser 

PrimarySMTP=objExchUsr.PrimarySMTPAddress
```

The problem arises when sometimes for a display name there is more than one result: `GetExchangeUser` does not retrieve the `PrimarySMTP` of the correct person.

I tried passing to the AddressEntries function the UPN, instead of the Display Name, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the recipient name is ambiguous, `Recipient.Resolve` will fail.

You cannot resolve ambiguous names using Outlook Object Model - you can loop through all GAL entries, but that will be too slow and will fail for large GAL containers.

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can use `PR_ANR` restriction to get all matches (that is what Outlook uses to show the list of ambiguous entries).

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use `RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx`

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = myolApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx(strDisplayname)
  Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
  Debug.Print "------------"
  for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "------------"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method which creates a [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object. It is used to verify a given name against an address book. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then    
   Set objExchUsr = myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
   PrimarySMTP = objExchUsr.PrimarySMTPAddress
 Else
   ' you need to iterate over all entries in the AB
 End If 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything else for that.

Comment: For an ambiguous name, `Recipient.Resolve` will fail.

Comment: Do you mean the `Resolved` property returns false?

Comment: Yes, it does return False